# How to self-update a single instance executable in Python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python application that is required to self-update. The unique challenge I'm facing is that I only have a single executable on my machine (App.exe). Any other "executables" are actually just shortcuts pointing back to this one. My updater is part of the same executable that it's trying to update. I thought of creating a backup of the current running executable, then launching the update process from the backup. However, I'm concerned about unpredictable behaviors and would like to avoid renaming or changing the original filename.

Here's a pseudocode of my current approach:

```
def installUpdates():
    # ... [Preliminary code: Check for updates, download, etc.]

    # Backup current executable without renaming
    current_exec_path = sys.executable
    backup_exec_path = create_backup_without_renaming(current_exec_path)

    # Run the installer from the backup
    proc = subprocess.Popen([backup_exec_path, args])
    proc.communicate()

    # Check installer's return code
    if proc.returncode == 0:
        # Success - assuming installer updated the original executable
        cleanup_backup(backup_exec_path) 
    else:
        # Error - handle error situation
        handle_error_scenario()

    # Kill current process
    kill_current_process()
```

Comment: You can't update an executable that's being executed. So you have two choices: Create a new executable and switch to it, or do the update in a separate process that restarts the application when it's done.

Comment: It's very common to load the new version as "app.new" then do two quick renames to swap out the old and swap in the new.  That leaves a very narrow window where things are incomplete, between the two renames.  It's not clear you can do any better.  The old app will continue to run even if it is renamed.